# Firefox Add-On signing error

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla, sign, jpm

I made an simple Add-On, and now I want to sign it, so it could work outside developer mode.
I read documentation on mozilla website, but when I try running jpm sign command, with my API key and secret, I get this error:

```
JPM [info] Created XPI for signing: C:\Users\STEFAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-unsigned-xpi-5168BFT2GMmLtNlm\@ffe-1.0.0.xpi
JPM [error] FAIL
Error: Received bad response from the server while requesting https://addons.mozilla.org/api/v3/addons/%40ffe/versions/1.0.0/

status: 401
response: {"detail":"Unknown JWT iss (issuer)"}
headers: {"allow":"GET, PUT, HEAD, OPTIONS","content-security-policy":"script-src 'self' https://addons.mozilla.org https://www.paypalobjects.com https://apis.google.com https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/ https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net; default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data: blob: https://www.paypal.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net https://static.addons.mozilla.net https://ssl.gstatic.com/ https://sentry.prod.mozaws.net; media-src https://videos.cdn.mozilla.net; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net; frame-src 'self' https://ic.paypal.com https://paypal.com https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.paypal.com; object-src 'none'; connect-src 'self' https://sentry.prod.mozaws.net; font-src 'self' https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net; report-uri /__cspreport__","content-type":"application/json","date":"Tue, 15 Mar 2016 22:27:05 GMT","server":"nginx","set-cookie":["multidb_pin_writes=y; expires=Tue, 15-Mar-2016 22:27:20 GMT; Max-Age=15; Path=/"],"strict-transport-security":"max-age=31536000","vary":"X-Mobile, User-Agent","www-authenticate":"JWT realm=\"api\"","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","x-frame-options":"DENY","x-xss-protection":"1; mode=block","content-length":"38","connection":"Close"}

at C:\Users\stefanmarkovic\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jpm\lib\amo-client.js:92:13
at tryCatchReject (C:\Users\stefanmarkovic\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jpm\node_modules\when\lib\makePromise.js:845:30)
at runContinuation1 (C:\Users\stefanmarkovic\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jpm\node_modules\when\lib\makePromise.js:804:4)
at Fulfilled.when (C:\Users\stefanmarkovic\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jpm\node_modules\when\lib\makePromise.js:592:4)
at Pending.run (C:\Users\stefanmarkovic\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jpm\node_modules\when\lib\makePromise.js:483:13)
at Scheduler._drain (C:\Users\stefanmarkovic\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jpm\node_modules\when\lib\Scheduler.js:62:19)
at Scheduler.drain (C:\Users\stefanmarkovic\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jpm\node_modules\when\lib\Scheduler.js:27:9)
at doNTCallback0 (node.js:419:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, as API Key I entered 
JWT issuer : user:*******:***
and as API secret I entered
JWT secret : *********************************************************

so my command looks like this:

```
jpm sign --api-key ${user:*******:***} --api-secret ${**************************************************************}
```

Comment: Your clock is probably off by more then 5s, try syncing it, see this issue - https://github.com/mozilla-jetpack/jpm/issues/469#issuecomment-174519406 - it links to a bunch of issues and the problem was the same, clocks were off.

Comment: tried changing time one minute backward as suggested on that link, and nothing changes

Comment: Setting it one minute back is not right. You should sync it with a clock. This clock is correct - http://www.unixtimestamp.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you including the `${}` in your command? If so, just remove it.

For example, if your `api-key` is `user:12345678:987` and your `api-secret` is `28934y23i4h32i4j23nk4j32443h` then your command should be like **this**:

```
jpm sign --api-key user:12345678:987 --api-secret 28934y23i4h32i4j23nk4j3244
```

**not:**

```
jpm sign --api-key ${user:12345678:987} --api-secret ${28934y23i4h32i4j23nk4j3244}
```

Comment: How much time will it take to generate signed extension? Do they manually review it?

Comment: Hi @Vrishank, it's all automatic. It just takes a couple of seconds.